# Is entry point on correct place?

Tags: c, windows, file, assembly, exe

In these days I was reading some PE executable specifications. Then I made small C program doing `push ebp, pop ebp` and I compiled it. After successful compilation I opened PE file in executable and looked on position `PE_magic + PE_header_size + PE_OPTHDR_entrypoint` where PE magic was first occurrence of "PE" string in file, PE_header_size was 24 and PE_OPTHDR was 16 according to PE & COFF specifications. On that position I found address 0x1000, but length of my file is only 0x600. So am I on correct position, or the entry point (which is by the way on 0x200) address is set incorrectly?

I am including image of my file contens and my code.

[image: 0x55 means PUSH EBP and 0x5D means POP EBP]

Code (in project properties I've unchecked addition of standard libraries):

```
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    __asm {
        push ebp
        pop ebp
    }
}
```

Comment: show me your code to read PE, at-least upto header info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see in the file does not match what it would look like in memory. As you can see, the file alignment is $200 while the in-memory section alignment is $1000. That usually means that the file will have less padding than the image it represents does.

More importantly, you can see that the section table entry for .text has a relative virtual address of $1000 (relative the Image Base) but a raw address of $200 (relative to the beginning of the file). Almost all fields that say where a certain thing is are RVA's, which means they store the offset of the thing they refer to from Image Base, in memory.

So no, the address is not set incorrectly - .text begins at $1000 (relative to Image Base) and that's where the Entry Point is pointing to.

Comment: So, optionaly, how can I calculate the real position of something within the file?

Comment: @user35443 I tried to put it all in a comment but it's a little long, see here: http://www.tech-juice.org/2011/02/21/portable-executable-converting-rva-to-file-offset-and-back/